# Hash password and return string with special characters

Tags: php, hash, special-characters, pbkdf2

I am trying to use a hashing algorithm that is really strong and outputs special characters in the encoded string in PHP. Currently I am using hash_pbkdf2 which I understand to be the most secure form of hashing at the moment but it doesn't output a string with special characters only uppercase and lowercase. Is there any way to modify it to do such or is there another algorithm that would work better? Maybe if I combined this with another encryption algorithm which would then take the output of the hash_pbkdf2 and encrypt it to something with special characters as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using it to hash passwords to store them password_hash() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) or crypt() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) are better suited

Comment: Use the new Password Hashing API with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` so it will always use the strongest available algorithm.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois but what if the algorithm changes then wont everything stop working? For example I have stored the encoded passwd in the db and then I try and check it and the security algorithm has changed, it would output a different result no?

Comment: No, used algo and cost is saved in the hash

Comment: But I am not comparing with the hash until I have completed the hashing process. ie for first time password->hash->hashedpwd1, second time password->hash->hashedpwd2. If I then do a str_cmp of hashedpwd1 and hashedpwd2 they would return different results?

Answer (score 0):

`hash_pbkdf2()` outputs a hex encoded result by default. You can pass in a `true` as the sixth function argument in order to receive a raw binary output, but then you get unprintable characters.

If you're interested in getting only printable characters, you can try encoding the result by changing the base from 16 (hex) to 94 (all printable ASCII characters). Here is an [example code](http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=139289).

Comment: thanks but I decided to use the password_hash function from php

Answer (score -2):

you can use this:

```
$input = "YourPassword";
$EncryptionKey = "sFdhgdvDRg4353FDgdfg";

 $encrypted = EncryptIt( $input);

echo "Encrypted: " . EncryptIt( $input ) . "<br/>";
echo "Decrypted: ". DecryptIt( $encrypted );



function EncryptIt( $q ) {
$cryptKey  = $EncryptionKey;
 $qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5(         $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
return( $qEncoded );
}

function DecryptIt( $q ) {
$cryptKey  = $EncryptionKey;
$qDecoded      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
return( $qDecoded );
}
```

Comment: sorry, this is by design not secure enough, I do not want something that can be decrypted

Comment: This is encryption, not hashing, and is pretty awful for passwords. Do not ever do this.